# Build monitor for TFS 2008 build server

Tags: tfs, build-process

We have about 6 TFS Projects with their own builds that we want to actively monitor.  Ideally it should show each of the builds along with their status: succeeded, partially succeeded, failed..

I don't need it to drive a light, rather I want a simple window as either a windows app or a web page.  I did come across the [Build Monitor on codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/BuildMonitor), but that seems to only drive twitter or some kind of light.

The built in Build Explorer only shows builds for a single TFS project, I need it to cross TFS projects.

Ultimately, this will be shown on a large wall mounted monitor in our Dev area.

Ideas?

Comment: take a look at http://tfsbuildinspector.codeplex.com

I have the same problem. finaly I had to write my own tool. last week I decided to publish the solution via codeplex. I removed the special features of it, however, I think this addin fits your problem. by the way, it may worth the effort.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299267/does-tfs-have-anything-like-cctray-for-build-notifications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Team Build Screen Saver seems to be exactly what you are looking for:

http://teambuildscreensaver.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/buildwallboard

for a single project implementation that I did as a code sample for talks I do on programming the Team Build API.  Robert Aquila took that sample and then made it do more stuff along with working for multiple projects here

http://raquila.com/software/team-foundation-server-build-notification-screen/

Comment: Robert Aquila's app is good.  Doesn't have all the functionality of the TFS Power Tools Build Notification but at the moment it is less flakey.

Answer (score 0):

All the client assemblies used by the tools (including Team Explorer) are documented in MSDN.

For the build client assemblies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc339575

For the rest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb130146