# Notify when build fails

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild

I've researched about how to send e-mails when build fails, but I only found personal options for this issue, changing my alerts configuration.

I want to send e-mails to users signed in the project. How can I configure this in my project configurations?

PS.: I'm using TFS from Visual studio 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're creating an alert in TFS 2013, you must specify the scope that the alert sites at ("Me" or "Team"). In TFS 2013, each Team Project will have a default team, so you can set the alert to be that specific team's alert, or a sub-team if you only want the alert to go to a subset of the overall Team Project. When you are configuring the alert in the alerts explorer, hit the **Subscriber** drop-down in the top right, and choose the appropriate team.

[image: Change scope of alert in TFS 2013]

Answer (score 1):

This may already be the site you found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181725.aspx (sorry if this isn't what you're asking)

I have some alerts set up to be sent to myself and a few other individuals.  And other alerts go to a larger distribution list.

Comment: The problem is not my personal configuration, I want to make my project send e-mails to envolved users

Comment: Even though you are logged in as yourself, you can still create alerts that are sent to more than just yourself, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the control panel of your TFS project. It's the same url as your TFS project page which ends with "_admin" (`http://yourtfsserver:8080/.../.../projectname/_admin`)

Click on the "Alerts" tab. From the left side pane open the "ProjectName Team Alerts" item and select the "Build Alerts". On the main frame you'll find the query options to build team wide build alerts.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you may use ccTray: http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet

Perhaps you will manage to configure it with the help of this stack: [Does TFS have anything like CCTray for Build Notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299267/does-tfs-have-anything-like-cctray)