# Alternatives to e-mails for alerts from TFS in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, push, alert

Are there other ways to receive alerts from TFS, besides e-mails? I would rather keep my e-mail inbox clean, and have some kind of notification icon or banner, like here on StackOverflow when you have new messages.

EDIT: In my case, it would be useful to know when changes have been pushed to trunk, so that I can keep my code synched and avoid big merges.

Answer (score 4):

Except emails you could also use some 3-rd party tool/extension to get the notification from TFS/Azure DevOps.

However as **a limitation**, most of them mainly only support the notification of CI build/release/work item area.

For example:

> ### Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio
>
> The [Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VSIDEDevOpsMSFT.ContinuousDeliveryToolsforVisualStudio) integrate build
>   notification directly into Visual Studio. This results in a toast
>   notification whenever you have Visual Studio open:
>
> [image]
>
> ### Catlight
>
> Another great tool to get build notifications is [Catlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Catlightio.CatLight), it
>   runs from the task tray and will even notify you when Visual studio
>   isn't open:
>
> [image]
>
> ### Siren of Shame
>
> And another option is [Siren of Shame](https://sirenofshame.com/BuildMonitor), which also offers
>   integration with a USB emergency light that will start blinking when
>   the build fails:
>
> [image]

More details please take a look at *jessehouwing* and *CJBS* 's reply in this question:

[Notifications for successful automated builds to each team member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318302/notifications-for-successful-automated-builds-to-each-team-member)